# how to get the count of the user from a table for male and female gender

Tags: mysql, activerecord

i am having a table tb_user in which the record are as like:

```
Name      gender   location  grewup

Arun       male     india    britain
sonia     female     USA     dubai
sheetal   female    india    Russia
```

what i want to do is to fetch the record on the basis of location:

```
Location        Total Count      Female     Male
United States       50             30        20
Canada              30             17        13
Lebanon             20             10        10
Germany             10              2         8
France               5              2         3

select `Location`, COUNT(id) as totalcount,(select COUNT(id) from tb_user where `gender` = 'Female') as female,(select COUNT(id) from tb_user where `gender` = 'Male') as male FROM tb_user GROUP BY `Location`
```

i have used the above query in this i am getting the total count of the user from different countries which satisfies one condition that is total count but i also want the number of female and male candidates but this query is providing the total number of males and females in each row.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM

(SELECT location, COUNT(id) as totalcount
FROM tb_user
GROUP BY location) as foobar

NATURAL JOIN

(SELECT location, COUNT(id) as female
FROM tb_user
GROUP BY location, gender
HAVING gender = 'female') as foo

NATURAL JOIN

(SELECT location, COUNT(id) as male
FROM tb_user
GROUP BY location, gender
HAVING gender = 'male') as bar

hope it works

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tb_user GROUP BY `Location`
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: your query is fetching the record with total count and total count of female and male, not the total count of the female and male candidate in that particular country

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this question,
for the users who need answer to this query is as :

```
select `Location`, COUNT(id) as totalcount, sum(IF(`gender` = 'Female',1,0)) as female,sum(IF(`gender` = 'Male',1,0)) as male FROM tb_user GROUP BY `Location`
```